# What are the best uses for VS command prompt?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What is the best way to use Visual Studio Command Prompt?
Tips, tricks and time savers.

Thanks

Comment: The only times I have used this command prompt is to access the .NET dissambler (idlasm) and the .NET registration tool (regasm). As pointed out by Hans, the .bat file updates the environment variables with paths to .NET components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what you are asking.  Maybe this: I keep it in the VS Tools menu so it is always handy and opens in the right folder, even for temporary projects.  Tools + External Tools, Add:

- Title = "Command prompt"
- Command = cmd.exe
- Arguments = /k "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
- Initial Directory = $(BinDir)

Tweak as necessary for other VS editions or platforms.

Comment: I was asking what can you do with this command prompt(updated environment vars). How is it useful? any particular good reasons to use it?

Comment: I run the SDK tools from it.  Popular choices are oleview, regasm, ildasm, undname, sn, msbuild, fuslogvw, gacutil, etc.  It does fall in the category of 'you don't know until you need it'.  Visual Studio is usually good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I use it to invoke `msbuild` manually, and paths etc. are set up correctly for this. Since our continuous integration server uses `msbuild`, it's essential for diagnosing/debugging related issues.